# How to remove Spinner's ellipsize or '...' at the end?

Tags: android, spinner

I made a few Spinners and the length(width) of Spinner is shorter than the name of some items.

For example, after choosing an item.

`[South K...▼]`

But what I want is this:

`[South Kore▼]`

(But not `[South Kore▼a]` nor overlapped.)

It seems like Spinner in Layout(XML) doesn't have any attributes like ellipsize. And I couldn't find any information online.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

My resources are here:

`1. Country Name Array in [strings.xml]`

```
<string-array name="countries_array">
    <item>Argentina</item>
    <item>Australia</item>
    <item>Austria</item>
    <item>Bangladesh</item>
    <item>Belgium</item>
    <item>Brazil</item>
    <item>Bulgaria</item>
    <item>Cambodia</item>
    <item>Canada</item>
    <item>Chile</item>
    <item>China</item>
    <item>Colombia</item>
    <item>Czech Republic</item>
    <item>Denmark</item>
    <item>Egypt</item>
    <item>Estonia</item>
    <item>Fiji</item>
    <item>Finland</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>Germany</item>
    <item>Greece</item>
    <item>Guam</item>
    <item>Hong Kong</item>
    <item>Hungary</item>
    <item>Iceland</item>
    <item>India</item>
    <item>Indonesia</item>
    <item>Iran</item>
    <item>Iraq</item>
    <item>Ireland</item>
    <item>Israel</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>Jamaica</item>
    <item>Japan</item>
    <item>Kazakhstan</item>
    <item>Laos</item>
    <item>Luxembourg</item>
    <item>Macau</item>
    <item>Malaysia</item>
    <item>Mexico</item>
    <item>Monaco</item>
    <item>Mongolia</item>
    <item>Morocco</item>
    <item>Mozambique</item>
    <item>Myanmar</item>
    <item>Nepal</item>
    <item>Netherlands</item>
    <item>New Zealand</item>
    <item>Nigeria</item>
    <item>North Korea</item>
    <item>Norway</item>
    <item>Pakistan</item>
    <item>Peru</item>
    <item>Philippines</item>
    <item>Poland</item>
    <item>Portugal</item>
    <item>Romania</item>
    <item>Russia</item>
    <item>Senegal</item>
    <item>Singapore</item>
    <item>South Africa</item>
    <item>South Korea</item>
    <item>Spain</item>
    <item>Sweden</item>
    <item>Switzerland</item>
    <item>Taiwan</item>
    <item>Thailand</item>
    <item>Tunisia</item>
    <item>Turkey</item>
    <item>Ukraine</item>
    <item>United Arab Emirates</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
    <item>United States</item>
    <item>Uzbekistan</item>
    <item>Vietnam</item>
</string-array>
```

`2. Spinner in the Layout`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/themeColor"
        tools:context="org.koreanlab.origol.activity.NavigationActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchbar_linearlayout_searchfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/category_spinner_searchfragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    >
                </Spinner>
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/subcategory_spinner_searchfragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    >
                </Spinner>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/iamlookingfor_edittext_searchfragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:hint="@string/iamlookingfor"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/country_spinner_searchfragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                    android:prompt="@string/country_spinner_title"
                    >

                </Spinner>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/city_spinner_searchfragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                    android:prompt="@string/city_spinner_title">

                </Spinner>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/article_listview_searchfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/searchbar_linearlayout_searchfragment"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/writebutton_searchfragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/blueMiddle"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_brush_black_48" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

`3. Java`

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_array));
    ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array));

    categorySP.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    countrySP.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    categoryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    categorySP.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    countrySP.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
```

Comment: Can you share the spinner adapter and xml?

Comment: updated the resources. @Udit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide custom layout for Spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter= new ArrayAdapter(mOwnerActivity, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<>());
```

Layout: R.layout.simple_list_item_1 -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

set adapter to your spinner:

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: What about `style` and `margin`?

Comment: just remove it apply your own style

Comment: Could you please give me additional information about `▼`? It seems it has margin-left and margin-right. How can I remove them? It looks like [South Kor  ▼  ] now. I want like [South Korea▼] without any spaces.

Comment: just remove the padding of textview and adjust textview according to your need.

Comment: That's the result of giving `0dp` to its padding. I guess the margin belongs to `▼` and even though I manipulate the TextView, It's not affected.

Answer (score 0):

**You to have no ellipse**

**use:** 
`android:ellipsize = "none"`

Comment: It doesn't have `ellipsize` attribute.

Comment: I guess @Shomu meant `custom spinner layout`. `custom spinner layout` is made of `TextView`. So, it has `ellipsize` attribute and I can customize it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create Adapter, you need to input three parameters.

`Context`, `Layout`, `ArrayList`

So, If you change the `Layout`(Customize). You can solve this problem.

This should change:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_array));
```

To:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_array));
```

NOTE: It is not android.R.layout.xxx. but R.layout.xxx WITHOUT android.

And create layout like this(under layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/spinner_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:maxLines="1"
    />
```

You can change the `@dimen` and `@color` as your taste.

What I did is:

`colors.xml`

```
<color name="black">#000</color>
```

`dimen.xml`

```
<dimen name="spinner_margin">0dp</dimen>
```